# TalkBack reads time wrong

Tags: android, time, talkback

When having a TextView containing `foo bar 04:58`, TalkBack will say `foo bar 4 hours 58 minutes` - it should be `foo bar 4 minutes 58 seconds`. On the other hand, `foo bar 04:24:05` works fine : `foo bar 4 hours 24 minutes 5 seconds`. My locale is french, by the way.

I thought of unelegant fixes for this :

- Replace each `mm:ss` by `00:mm:ss`
- Replace each `mm:ss` by `mm minutes ss seconds`

Is there a better solution to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the few times when I recommend overriding the text with a content description.  You have to expand it out.

So let's say you have a TextView

```
textView.setText("2:45")

textView.setContentDescription("2 minutes 45 seconds")
```

Content descriptions on text views act as alternative text and will be read out instead. This actually creates other accessibility issues.  Imagine an AT that read out both the Text and the Content Description, instead of using the content description as an override... UGH.  But in the current Android Accessibility ecosystem, where TalkBack has an overwhelming market share this solution isn't completely evil. Ideally, the Text To Speech engine would NOT be stupid. But, since the TTS engine is stupid, we have to change the text TalkBack sees in order for the read out to be reasonable.

You can also leave it be, and note that TalkBack users have the ability to explore text by character if they'd like, so they could figure out the weird TTS auto formatting.  You could also trying changing your view to look like this instead:

```
textView.setText("2m 45s");
```

Although, if I remember correctly the TTS Engine will expand this to "2 meters forty-fives"... awesome.

EDIT: I imagine this line of code will help with your other problem.

```
timeString.replaceAll("([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})", "$1 minutes $2 seconds");
```

Comment: This is really smart ! I'll try this as soon as I can. And I can confirm that `2m` is `2 meters`...

Comment: However it doesn't work for dynamic loaded text views : if I have in my application an HTTP request which gives me `14:24` and sets this as text, I can't put a content description

Comment: A text view is a text view.  Whether it's loaded dynamically or not.  Sounds to me like you have a separate question here...  but nothing about this solution is specific to the way any particular view is loaded.

Comment: Well if I format the time manually in my app, from a timestamp for instance, I can format it once using `mm:ss` for the text and once using `mm minutes ss seconds` for the content description. If I make a request and get `14:21`, I can only set the text, unless I find a dirty way to reformat it

Comment: I will try, thanks :) I didn't know that `replaceAll` supported `$x` parameters in the replacement string.